# C: how to create an empty STRING?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Please I have been struggling for 5 hours on this, I know how to create a empty char it's like this :

```
char c[] = '';
```

but how can I create en empty STRING ? (because I want to use it as a temporary place to store other strings)

```
char temporary[] = "";
error : array type 'char [1]' is not assignable
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.   What do you mean by an "empty char"?   In any event, it is not possible in C to magically create something that can be used to contain an arbitrary and changeable string of arbitrary length, unless you dynamically allocate and manage memory.      Also, the second example (in the form you've shown it) is valid - if you're getting an error from that, your code differs in some way.   Consider providing an actual sample of actual code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: `tempo = "";` Assuming `tempo` is a `char` array, you can't do that. Try `tempo[0] = '\0'`. You could also do: `strcpy(temp, "");` Or to completely clear it: `memset(tempo, 0, sizeof(tempo);`. But that's probably not necessary.

Comment: can I do strcpy(temp, ""); without having said what temp is ???

Comment: I can't use strcpy if temp is not DEFINED

Comment: @masterCUCK9 A typo. I meant to type `tempo`. As in: `strcpy(tempo, "");`

Comment: YES ? but tempo is not defined !! How can I call strcpy(tempo, "");  just like that ?? My question is how to CREATE THIS

Comment: Huh? You have a `tempo` variable in you code....<shrug> Please read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: tempo is the empty string I am asking to create

Comment: You have 2 questions then: 1. How to create an empty string. 2. How to reset back to an empty string after use. See @JohnBode's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399338/669576) as it answers both questions.

Comment: All variables must be defined before they can be passed to a function in C.

Comment: yes !! but how to define TEMPO please .... I can't create the empty string

Comment: @masterCUCK9 There are currently 2 answers posted to your question. Did you read either one? They both show how to create an empty string.

Comment: i see the problem was there i read them but i am a cuck sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a buffer to hold the string contents:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256 // or whatever size you need

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE+1] = {0}; // +1 for string terminator, 
                                  // = {0} initializer zeroes out entire buffer
```

To *assign* a string to this buffer, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy( buffer, "some string" );
```

To *append* a string to this buffer, use `strcat`:

```
strcat( buffer, "more string" );
```

**EDIT**

Now that you've edited your question, the problem is the line

```
tempo = "";
```

An array expression like `tempo` may not be the target of the `=` operator; you *must* use a library function like `strcpy` to assign string values.  If you want to set `tempo` to an empty string, you can do any one of the following:

```
strcpy( tempo, "" );
```

or

```
tempo[0] = 0;
```

or

```
tempo[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: I would actually `memset` `tempo` to its size as 0's to the entire buffer is reset instead of just the first character.

Comment: @ritlew: It kind of depends on what the OP is wanting to do - if all he needs to do is make sure `tempo` contains an empty string before a `strcpy` operation, then setting the initial element to 0 is sufficient.  If he's writing this buffer to a file or something, then yes, it would be safer to zero out all the unused elements.

Comment: Well if the string is `"Hello\0"`, then it becomes `"\0ello\0"`. So if they were to `strncpy` 2 characters `"Hi"` into the buffer, it becomes `"Hillo\0"`.

Comment: AAAAYYYAAA I FOUND OUT THE PROBLEM

Comment: @ritlew: And this is one of the reasons I never use `strncpy`.

Answer (score 1):

In `C` you have to create a temporary buffer all the time. The most typical way to do this is to write a line of code like this:

```
char temp_buffer[256];
```

This buffer will have 256 characters of space available to be able to put strings in.